# UISwipeGestureRecognizer extra argument 'target' in call for Archive project but not for Build project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiswipegesturerecognizer

If I Archive my project I receive `Extra argument in 'target' in call` but I do not receive this error if I Build the project. If I remove the `target` parameter name then I receive an error if I build.

```
let rightSwipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self,    action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
```

Comment: Encountered this issue in Xcode 6.1. Had to update to Xcode 6.2 beta to get rid of this error.

Comment: I'm getting this on Xcode 6.1. It won't compile in Release configuration. So annoying. This is the last time I use Swift for a few months - it's been a ridiculously painful build for a simple app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue today where I couldn't archive even though I did not change any of the files in days.

I restarted xcode, tried to archive again and it worked.  This is an xcode bug.